# Recibir los datos del request

Tags: c#

Quiero saber como puedo ingresar a los datos que se reciben al momento de ejecutar un request, para poder ingresar al json que me retorna, en postman muestra un json.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Danny, lo que quieres hacer es relativamente sencillo. Pero debes darnos tu código para que podamos ayudarte, o mostrar lo que has intentado hacer.

Comment: Hola, es un API, un WebForm o MVC? como dice Hugo, mostranos algo de codigo para poderte ayudar.